# DIV tag close right after another div open

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap my div into another div

I have this code

```
<div id="div_fourD_container" style="display: none;">

</div>

<div id="big_rate_div" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="small_rate_div" class="form-group">
</div>
```

In my html code it doesn't look this way, I din't add the  after fourD_container

it just add itself when big_rate_div comes in.

What I wanna do is have a container (div_fourD_container) to wrap big_rate_div and small_rate_div with style hidden together

in this way

```
<div id="div_fourD_container" style="display: none;">


<div id="big_rate_div" class="form-group" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div id="small_rate_div" class="form-group">
</div>

</div>
```

I don't know why the  was added in, its not in my php code or so

```
<div id="div_fourD_container">

<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>

<div id="big_rate_div" class="form-group">
<tr><td width="25%">
<label for="big_rate">Big Rate</label>
</td><td>
<b>1.60</b>
</td></tr>
</div>

<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr>

<div id="small_rate_div" class="form-group">
<tr><td width="25%">
<label for="big_rate">Small Rate</label>
</td><td>
<b>0.70</b>
</td></tr>
</div>

</div>
```

This my html code.. above, as you can see, the  come in so randomly I not sure why, I got this output by inspect element of my page using google chrome to debug.

How do I fix this issue so I can actually use the style: hidden on all my div inside big_fourD_container

which is big_rate_div and small_rate_div and the content in between   of big_fourD_container

Comment: u have php code from what i understood? please show us that as well

Comment: You can still use a CSS rule for all your containers inside your div to hide: #inside big_fourD_container div { display: none } - so you dont need inline CSS.

Comment: @derdida i need javascript because i will it unhide it later by a button, so my intention is to group them together using a div first

Comment: how come you have tr/td isnide a div and not inside a table elem ?

Comment: oh wow. This is so very invalid html. `<tr>` have to be the direct child of a `<table>` or `<tbody>`,`<thead>`. also the value of `id` have to be unique for the whole document. Also you can not have `<td>Column value</td><span>What i forgot...</span>` It's either table content or something else, but please, not this.

Comment: @SergioWizenfeld the php code I refer to is the html code u see at the bottom of my question. thats what it is, you realize I din't close the div tag, but it close by itself when I inspect element using google chrome, thats why my small and big rate div was not hidden as they are not wrap by the container.

Comment: @NicoO i din't paste the full table, is it not valid to use div with table ? I need the table to organize my text and stuffs.

Comment: @PabloRincon , the table code is not paste fully. this is what its going on table , inside have div, and I wanna hide part of the table code with div, is it achieveable, each tr have their own div like big_rate_div and small_rate_div

Comment: you can use `<div>` inside of a `<td>` or `<th>`. But it is invalid in the way you did it. [Read this](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/)

Comment: @NicoO, you solve my issue ! Thanks and you enlighten me greatly.

Comment: Glad the heads up helped you. Have fun :)